# Not inside a git repository

Tags: magit

magit-version: Magit 20170407.2107, Git (unknown), Emacs 25.1.1, darwin
git version 2.12.2
OS x 10.12.4

git status on command line works fine
git rev-parse --git-dir gives .git

magit-status asks for a directory, then asks to "Create repository in xxx?", then "user-error: Not inside a Git repository"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

So the answer for me was:

```
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
   :if (memq window-system '(mac ns))
   :ensure t
   :config
   (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

in my init.el